# Can I have a column in a DataGridView that only word wraps on line breaks?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView.  Some of the columns hold long text data so I have set:

```
_dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
```

This columns are breaking on spaces as well as carriage returns.

I would like the column to expand to be a wide as the longest line in the text while at the same time wrapping on carriage returns.  So not wrapping on spaces.

How would I do this?

Adding this doesn't do what I want.

```
_dataGridView..AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Calling :

```
_dataGridView.AutoResizeColumns();
```

after you set your datasource.

You can also resize a specific column with options :

```
_dataGridView.AutoResizeColumn(0, DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);
```

Edit , this works for me :

[image]

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>();

            myList.Add(new MyClass() { URL ="AAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAA \r AAAAAAAAAAAAAA" });
            myList.Add(new MyClass() { URL = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAA \r AAAAAAAAAAAAAA" });
            myList.Add(new MyClass() { URL = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA \r AAAAAAAAAAAAAA" });
            myList.Add(new MyClass() { URL = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA \r AAAAAAAAAAAAAA" });


            dataGridView1.DataSource = myList;
            dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
            dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns();
            dataGridView1.AutoResizeRows();
        }
```

Comment: This doesn't work because in order to use WrapMode I have to set;             _dataGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;  and that stops AutoResizeColumns(); from working

Comment: You're right. Replacing _dataGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells with dataGridView1.AutoResizeRows(); works fine.  Thanks.